# OnDisappearing and OnAppearing overrides cannot be treated as guaranteed indications of page navigation? Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am adding navigation to a Xamarin.Forms application. I need a method gets executed every time I am navigating away from a page. I want to override the [OnDisappearing](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnDisappearing/) method from the [Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Page/) base class. The problem is that in the online Xamarin book, on the [navigation chapter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/hierarchical/) I found this statement:

> Calls to the [OnDisappearing](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnDisappearing/) and [OnAppearing](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnAppearing/) overrides cannot be
>   treated as guaranteed indications of page navigation. For example, on
>   iOS, the OnDisappearing override is called on the active page when the
>   application terminates.

Does this mean that the OnDesappeating method does not get executed every single time right when navigating to another page?

Answer (score 0):

These methods are raised in different places in iOS and Android. So for example, OnAppearing will be called in OnAttachedToWindow in [PageRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/PageRenderer.cs) in Android, but **OnAttachedToWindow** is not the same meaning of "navigating to a page"; Some times it's called earlier than expected. TabLayout, for example, will pre-init the tabs near by the current tab, and OnAttachedToWindow will be called for all these tabs.

Comment: So I understand that the behavior can be different for Android and iOS, but how are they different specifically (in terms of behavior)?

Comment: and are you saying they don't always get called when expected?

Comment: As far as i know on Android they are even called when you lock your phone Screen and unlock again. Even when you take the app into the Background. Thats why i gave up using them